# How to pass a file path to the program via command line argument

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have 5 files, which I  have parsed. They are text files, and I dont know how to pass them to the program via command line arguemnt. I am using visual studio, and C sharp. When I go into `Project>Properties>Debug>Command Line Argument>` Do I just type in the files? Like `File01.txt,File02.txt` etc...

Comment: Do you want to tell the program the *names* of the files (maybe with a path) and let it open them, or pipe the contents into the program?

Comment: Do you mean parsed, or passed -- as in someone passed the files to you?

Comment: Tim Barrass - I mean parsed. I have 5 pre-defined text files, which I have successfully parsed no issue. I just had trouble getting my head around how to pass the file paths to the program via command line argument.

Comment: Doctor Love -  Yes you are correct I want to pipe the contents into the program. I have already parsed the 5 files, so when I compile my code the 5 text files are printed on the console. I just need to pass the 5 files to the program via command line argument. I hope I dont sound confusing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way is to realise that command line arguments are passed to you as an array of strings in your Main(...) method.

```
class TestClass
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Display the number of command line arguments:
        System.Console.WriteLine(args.Length);

        foreach(var arg in args)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(arg);
        }
    }
}
```

(Broadly from: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acy3edy3.aspx)

Specifically in answer to your question -- yes, in the debug tab, but they need to be space-separated, not comma separated.

If you actually want to open and read the files, you'll need something like (assuming they're text files):

```
int counter = 0;
string line;

using(var file = new System.IO.StreamReader(arg))
{
    while((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine (line);
        counter++;
    }
}
```

(Broadly from: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/aa287535%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: Note that if an argument contains spaces it should be surrounded with quotes i.e. `"my argument"`

Answer (score 0):

In your Main method, you can process your arguments in the following way:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    if (args.Length > 0)
    {
        foreach (string p in args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(p);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Empty input parameters");
    }
}
```

When you run your program from command line, you have to use the following syntax:

```
C:\>yourprogram.exe firstfile.txt secondfile.xls thridfile.dat
```